# Access SQLite Helper From Adapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Code

```
public class ChatData extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MessagePlus";

    public ChatData(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
    public Cursor getAllQuestions3(MessagesAdapter usageSettings2) {
        return this.getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_CHAT_DATA,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
final ChatData mHelper = new ChatData(this);
final Cursor csr = mHelper.getAllQuestions3(this);
```

Nothing is working for context in adapter. This shows message to change the Helper classes context to the Adapters name and if i do that theres a red line under context in the helper... If i directly try to access like **ChatData.getWritableDatabase** it shows that u cant access a non static method from a static class and if i make that method in helper static it shows error there saying class cant be static... one error is leading to another and i dont know what to do so can someone help me out please

**EDIT**

Full Adapter Code

```
public class MessagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessagesAdapter.MessageViewHolder>{

private List<SQLiteHelper> mMessagesHelperList;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

ChatData mHelper = new ChatData(this);
Cursor csr = mHelper.getAllQuestions3();
public MessagesAdapter(List<SQLiteHelper> mMessagesHelperList) {
    this.mMessagesHelperList = mMessagesHelperList;
}

public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView messageText;

    public MessageViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        messageText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.message_text_layout);
    }
}

@Override
public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View V = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_activity_chat,parent,false);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    return new MessageViewHolder(V);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String mSender = null;
    String mMessage = null;
    String mTime;
    String mSeen = null;

    String mTimer;
    String mType;
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        mSender = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_SENDER));
        mMessage = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_MESSAGE));
        mTime = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_TIME));
        mSeen = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_SEEN));
        mTimer = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_TIMER));
        mType = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_TYPE));
    }

    SQLiteHelper messagesHelper = mMessagesHelperList.get(position);



@Override
public  int getItemCount() {
    return mMessagesHelperList.size();
}
```

}

Activity

```
    final MainData mHelper = new MainData(this); //Change the name to your Helper Class name
    final Cursor csr = myDBHlpr.getAllQuestions3(this);
     messageList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        String mSender = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_SENDER));
        String mMessage = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_MESSAGE));
        String mTime = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_TIME));
        String mSeen = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_SEEN));
        String mTimer = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_TIMER));
        String mType = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_TYPE));

        messages.add(new SQLiteHelper(mSender, mMessage, mTime, mSeen, mTimer, mType));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will likely cause some of your issues. That is you are saying that the method should be passed a MesagesAdapter, when as it stands there is no reason to pass anything into the **getAllQuestions3** method.

```
public Cursor getAllQuestions3(MessagesAdapter usageSettings2) {
    return this.getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_CHAT_DATA,null,null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

Trying changing the above to

```
public Cursor getAllQuestions3() {
    return this.getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_CHAT_DATA,null,null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

and use

```
ChatData mHelper = new ChatData(this);
Cursor csr = mHelper.getAllQuestions3();
```

instead of

```
final ChatData mHelper = new ChatData(this,ChatData.DATABASE_NAME,null,ChatData.DATABASE_VERSION);
final Cursor csr = mHelper.getAllQuestions3(this);
```

Noting that the above lines should be in the Activity's onCreate method or a method invoked from onCreate so that you have a valid context (i.e. this).

### Edit 1

Note that the above has been changed as according to ChatData you need to provided 4 parameters for the instantiation of a ChatData object.

I'd suggest changing the constructor to :-

```
public ChatData(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

and then you could use `ChatData mHelper = new ChatData(this);`.

---

### Working Example

The following is a working example based upon the code you have given.

The database helper **ChatData.java**

```
public class ChatData extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MessagePlus";
    public static final String TABLE_CHAT_DATA = "chatdata";
    public static final String COL_CHATDATA_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_CHATDATA_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
    public static final String COL_CHATDATA_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String COL_CHATDATA_USER = "user";

    public ChatData(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crt_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_CHAT_DATA + "(" +
                COL_CHATDATA_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COL_CHATDATA_TIMESTAMP + " TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP," +
                COL_CHATDATA_MESSAGE + " TEXT, " +
                COL_CHATDATA_USER + " INTEGER" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
    public Cursor getAllQuestions3() {
        return this.getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_CHAT_DATA,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    public long addMessage(String message, long user) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_CHATDATA_MESSAGE,message);
        cv.put(COL_CHATDATA_USER,user);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.insert(TABLE_CHAT_DATA,null,cv);
    }
}
```

- Note modified to crate a table and to allow rows to be added to the table.
- **Note the constructor.**

The Custom Adapter (Cursor Adapter) **MessageAdapter.java**

```
public class MessageAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public MessageAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
        super(context, c, autoRequery);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rv = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.messagelist_item,
                parent,
                false
        );
        return rv;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        TextView mUser = view.findViewById(R.id.user);
        TextView mTimestamp = view.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        TextView mMessage = view.findViewById(R.id.message);

        mUser.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ChatData.COL_CHATDATA_USER)));
        mTimestamp.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ChatData.COL_CHATDATA_TIMESTAMP)));
        mMessage.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ChatData.COL_CHATDATA_MESSAGE)));
    }
}
```

The layout used in the list **messagelist_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timestamp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The code in the Activity to list the messages via the adapter (**MainActivty.java**)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ChatData mDBHlpr;
    Cursor mCsr;
    MessageAdapter mMesaageAdapter;
    ListView mMessageList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mMessageList = this.findViewById(R.id.messagelist);
        mDBHlpr = new ChatData(this);
        addSomeData();
        mCsr = mDBHlpr.getAllQuestions3();
        mMesaageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this,mCsr,false);
        mMessageList.setAdapter(mMesaageAdapter);

    }

    private void addSomeData() {
        mDBHlpr.addMessage("Hello",1);
        mDBHlpr.addMessage("Hi",2);
        mDBHlpr.addMessage("How are you?",1);
        mDBHlpr.addMessage("I'm OK thanks, and you?",2);
        mDBHlpr.addMessage("Good.",1);
    }
}
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: what about final ChatData mHelper = new ChatData(this);
 Stil sjhows a red line under this

Comment: ChatData mHelper = new ChatData(this);
 This line should be in the adapter class and not an activity... Custom adapter for a recyclerview... should be accessed in that class so im getting trouble

Comment: To instantiate mHelper you MUST pass a context this will only be a context in an activity. I suggest that you edit your post to include the adapter code in full and also the activity (or fragment of an activity) in which it is used. Typically an adpater would have a Context passed to it.

Comment: @LaylaMcKenzy added a working example that display the chat messages in a ListView with a custom adapter **MessageAdapter** based upon the avilable code.

Comment: Im sorry that i hadnt uploaded the full code.. Can u check and tell me where i ave gone wrong now please?

Comment: Also im not able to use ChatData mHelper = new ChatData(this); Its showing red line under this

Comment: @LaylaMcKenzy because **this** is  not a context and because you can only use **this**  on an instantiated object not as a class variable (even then this would not be a context). Will have a look as you've now added the adapter.

Comment: I just used view.getContext and it worked... thanks for rest though